Forth: What is the standard way to define a word using machine code?
I wrote a Forth interpreter in Assembler (core set), but is there a standard way to define a Forth word using Assembler instructions or directly machine code?
Example
I want to define "+" (addition) using Assembler ("::" separate assembler instructions) like this
: + ASMSTART pop hl :: pop de :: add hl de :: push hl ASMEND ;

or directly giving the op codes (for Z80 in this case), which is easier:
: + OPSTART E1 D1 19 E5 OPMEND ;

where ASMSTART-ASMEND and OPSTART-OPMEND are builtin words made for this purpose.
Currently, "+" is a builtin in the interpreter code, like other arithmetic, logical and bit manipulation operations.

Not really.  Each Forth does it however it likes.

As ruvim says, typically CODE and END-CODE are used for this purpose, analogously to : and ;.
Also, a common way to implement an assembler in Forth is by using a separate vocabulary or wordlist named something like ASSEMBLER, containing words corresponding to assembler mnemonics.  This lends itself nicely to an RPN-syntax assembler.  So for instance HL could be defined in this vocabulary as a constant, and POP as a word which assembles a pop instruction, using the value from the top of the stack to determine the register operand.  Your definition of + could then look something like
ASSEMBLER ALSO
CODE + ( x y -- sum )
   HL POP
   DE POP
   DE HL ADD
   HL PUSH
END-CODE
   


Regarding ASSEMBLER ALSO — usually CODE itself adds ASSEMBLER into the search order, and END-CODE restores the search order. Therefore there is no need to do it explicitly.

Words defined in machine code are sometimes called "primitives" or "code definitions". Obviously, it is in principle impossible to standardize a way to define the behavior for such a word.
And although the standard specifies the word code to create a new primitive, the behavior of that primitive is defined in implementation-defined manner.
Typical use:
code foo ( x1 -- x2 )
  \ assembler code
  \ syntax/language is defined by the Forth system
  \ ...
end-code

